# No type intellisense autocompletion in Class file in VS2012, but controllers are fine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I am creating a class in a seperate ".cs" class file. I am using EF type and when I type them out ie "Order" they appear fine and valid. However when I start to type them out I am not getting any intellisense autocomplete functionality on the type ie "Ord" -> "Order". This works fine in the controller files, but not in the class files.

I was using ReSharper, but suspended it to check it was not to do with it, but the problem carried on. I also checked in Tools>Text Editor>C#>Intellisense. Still confused

Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, sorted it. It seems this was due to the fact that I accidentally put this file in the root folder. As soon as I put it in the "Models" folder it worked fine.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer and accept it just to make sure the question gets recognised as having been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorted it. It seems this was due to the fact that I accidentally put this file in the root folder. As soon as I put it in the "Models" folder it worked fine.